# The client_id field in extensions table is not updated to 1

Tags: joomla-3.x, update

When I install the component com_xyz, the extensions table is updated with client_id=1.  But when a package or library is getting installed this field is updated to 0.

Why? Because of this the update server is not able to find the updates for my package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to joomla, Client ID is used by modules, templates and languages to specify which application (client) they should run in (e.g. administrator or site).

client_Id = 1 means admin access
client_Id = 0 means frontend access

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense. But why the joomla updater (while finding updates) is looking only for the extensions with client_id = 1?

Comment: @Malaiselvan Why do you think it's looking form only extensions with `client_id=1`

Comment: @Rene Korss That is how the updater.php is coded.. Yesterday I had a tough time to find why my updates or not able to find. On seeing the core joomla programs I see a place where extensions are selected based on client_id. I am not right now in front of my laptop. Later I will update with the details.

Comment: Okay. Will wait for that, because I can't find such code in source.

Comment: @Rene Korss Just ignore my previous comment.. It was a long day yesterday.... I guess I nail down the problem. When I install the package it stores with `client_id` as 0. But when an update is available for that package the updater (when finding updates) considers the package as `client_id` as 1 and it is ignoring the update... Refer my other thread at http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/15083/2239. That's the reason I flip the client Id as 1 after install